# group homomorphism of permutation groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose I let $$\begin{align}
g_{1} &= y_{1}y_{2} + y_{3}y_{4}\\
g_{2} & = y_{1}y_{3} + y_{2}y_{4}\\
g_{3} & = y_{1}y_{4} + y_{2}y_{3}.\end{align}$$ The group $S_{4}$ (permutations of the set $\{1,2,3,4\}$), which acts on the set $\{y_{1},y_{2},y_{3},y_{4}\}$. This yields a permutation of the set $\{g_{1},g_{2},g_{3}\}$. This is a group homomorphism (call it $f$) from $S_{4}$ to $S_{3}$.

There are two things I am curious about. What are all the elements in the kernel of $f$? Also, after doing physical examples with this, I am pretty sure the ker $f$ is an Abelian group, although I am unsure how to prove it.

Comment: You can weed out the elements of $\ker f$ by intersecting stabilizers of $g_{1,2,3}$. And $\ker f$ has size $4!/3!=4$ so it must be abelian. There are rough duplicates of this question, although they probably pertain to partitions of the set $\{1,2,3,4\}$ instead of polynomials.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: First convince yourself that this homomorphism is surjective.  One you know that you know that the kernel has order $|S_4|/|S_3| = 4$.

Now we just need to find 3 nontrivial elements in the kernel.  If you look at $g_1$ it's obvious that it's fixed by $(1 \ 2)(3 \ 4)$.  Check that this fixes $g_2$ and $g_3$ as well.  Now look at the "obvious" permutations that fix $g_2$ and $g_3$.  Check if these are in the kernel.